# How can I declare that the return type of a member method is that of `self`?

Tags: python, typing

I want to properly annotate the `__add__` method in the `Incrementable` class of the following program.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from attr import dataclass
from datetime import date, timedelta


class Incrementable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __add__(self, n: int):
        return NotImplemented


@dataclass
class MyInt(Incrementable):
    n: int

    def __add__(self, n: int) -> MyInt:
        return MyInt(self.n + n)


@dataclass
class MyDate(Incrementable):
    d: date

    def __add__(self, n: int) -> MyDate:
        return MyDate(self.d + timedelta(days=n))
```

The points are:

1. `MyInt` and `MyDate` are incrementable, that is, they each have a method that accepts an integer and returns an incremented value of their type.
2. To abstract this behavior, I introduced the abstract class `Incrementable`.

The problem is:
I think the `__add__` method should return a value that is of the same type as `self`, but I don't know how should represent that by type annotation.

How can I do ?

Comment: Is [PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) what you’re loooking for?

Comment: does mypy complain if you annotate the abstract method as `-> Incrementable`? You might consider using `typing.Protocol` https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#recursive-protocols instead of/in conjunction with `ABC`

Comment: @Anentropic It won’t complain on the above, but the result type will be `Incrementable` instead of the respective subclass, so mypy will complain once you try to invoke subclass methods on the result value. Hence why we need to use a type var here (though your suggestion about using a protocol instead of nominal subtyping also has merit).

Comment: After adding `Incrementable` to the result type of `Incrementable.__add__`, mypy doesn't give any errors for 
`i: Incrementable = MyInt(10); i += 10` or `d: Incrementable = MyDate(date.today()); d += 10`, as in https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=bc91246a27cab8bcf545ad35a146ebf9. Could you give a complete example that leads to mypy errors?

Comment: @tueda but he doesn't want `i` to be annotated with `Incrementable`, they want it to be `i: MyInt = MyInt(10); i += 1`, the the PEP 673 link

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes but the concrete classes already override that with `-> MyInt` and `-> MyDate` so we only need mypy to understand that they are covariant

Comment: Here is a playground showing it working https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=fe0b1d7e79d4f0a33b84f804d351b532&flags=check-untyped-defs%2Cdisallow-incomplete-defs%2Cdisallow-untyped-calls%2Cdisallow-untyped-decorators%2Cdisallow-untyped-defs

Comment: Oh, `dataclass` is not one from the standard library, but from [attrs](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/)? Does it make any difference in the behavior of the code??

Comment: @Anentropic thank you. I found annotating with `-> Incrementable` works file in my environment. To Konrad and tueda: thank you for suggestive disscussion :)